# Flex - Typed ArrayCollection as Horizontallist's dataprovider

Tags: apache-flex, dataprovider, arraycollection, typed

I have an ArrayCollection of  objects. 
I'm passing this array to a horizontallist as a dataprovider and I'm using a custom itemRenderer.

When executing the application, the horizontallist is displaying

```
[object CustomClass][object CustomClass][object CustomClass][object CustomClass]
```

I've tried casting each object in the itemrenderer as following:

```
<mx:Label text="{(data as CustomClass).label1}"/>
```

But it's not working...

Thanks for any help you can provide.
Regards,

BS_C3

---

Edit - 09 March 2010

Let's go for some more code =)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">

    <mx:Component id="Item">
        <mx:VBox width="180">
            <mx:HBox width="100%">
                <mx:Spacer width="100%"/>
                <mx:Button label="x"/>
            </mx:HBox>
            <mx:Image id="thumbnail"/>
            <mx:Label width="100%" horizontalCenter="0" text="Collection"/>
            <mx:HBox width="100%">
                <mx:Label width="100" text="GIA"/>
                <mx:Label text="{data.charg_st}"/>
            </mx:HBox>
            <mx:HBox width="100%">
                <mx:Label width="100" text="Finger Size"/>
                <mx:Label text="xxxxxx"/>
            </mx:HBox>
            <mx:HBox width="100%">
                <mx:Label width="100" text="Carat"/>
                <mx:Label text="{data.carats}"/>
            </mx:HBox>
            <mx:HBox width="100%">
                <mx:Label width="100" text="Color"/>
                <mx:Label text="{data.color}"/>
            </mx:HBox>
            <mx:HBox width="100%">
                <mx:Label width="100" text="Clarity"/>
                <mx:Label text="{data.clarity}"/>
            </mx:HBox>
            <mx:HBox width="100%">
                <mx:Label width="100" text="Shop"/>
                <mx:Label text="{data.lgort_fp}"/>
            </mx:HBox>
            <mx:HBox width="100%">
                <mx:Label width="100" text="Resizing"/>
                <mx:Label text="{data.resizing}"/>
            </mx:HBox>
            <mx:HBox width="100%">
                <mx:Label width="100" text="Price Excl. VAT"/>
                <mx:Label text="{data.net_price_fp}"/>
            </mx:HBox>
        </mx:VBox>
    </mx:Component>


    <mx:HorizontalList
        dataProvider="{GlobalData.instance.tray}" 
        columnCount="4"
        rowCount="1"
        horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
        itemRenderer="{Item}"
    />
</mx:Canvas>
```

FYI, the horizonalList dataprovider is an ArrayCollection of  objects.

Now, the horizontallist is displaying empty items... with the correct width... 
The arraycollection is not empty (I'm using an alert on the click event on an item, and I do retrieve the expected data).

Hope this will help >_<

Regards,
BS_C3

Comment: Can you add more code or a complete test case ?

Comment: Nobody has a solution?

I've kept trying different solutions it still doesn't work. Everything that's inside the itemrenderer appears "BLANK". 
It's like the item was there, but something is hiding it. 

I've added an itemClick event to display the item's data, and it does display... 

I've also recreated the arraycollection as an arraycollection of objects... And it does not change the horizontallist's behaviour. Still getting a blank item...

I really do not understand >_<

Any clue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve my issue.

When I removed the width property of the itemrenderer's vbox, all data appeared in the horizontalList.
Why? I wouldn't know why but it seems like it was positionning the data somewhere out of the visible scope of the horizontallist (huh??).

The thing is that everything is working now. And for the final code, there you have:

HorizontalList:

```
<mx:HorizontalList id="hlist"
    dataProvider="{TrayData.instance.itemsCollection}" 
    columnCount="{TrayData.instance.hlistColumns}"
    rowCount="1"
    itemRenderer="components.TrayItem"
    horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
    horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"
    borderStyle="none"
    horizontalScrollPosition="{TrayData.instance.hsPosition}"
    />
```

ItemRenderer:

```
<mx:VBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" >

    <mx:HBox width="100%">
        <mx:Spacer width="100%"/>
        <mx:Button label="x"/>
    </mx:HBox>
    <mx:HBox width="100%">
        <mx:Spacer width="15%"/>
        <mx:VBox width="70%">
            <mx:Image id="thumbnail" horizontalAlign="center"/>
            <mx:Label width="100%" textAlign="center" text="Collection"/>
            <mx:HBox width="100%">
                <mx:VBox id="labelBox" width="100">
                    <mx:Label width="100" text="GIA"/>
                    <mx:Label width="100" text="Finger Size"/>
                    <mx:Label width="100" text="Carat"/>
                    <mx:Label width="100" text="Color"/>
                    <mx:Label width="100" text="Clarity"/>
                    <mx:Label width="100" text="Shop"/>
                    <mx:Label width="100" text="Resizing"/>
                    <mx:Label width="100" text="Price"/>
                </mx:VBox>
                <mx:VBox id="dataBox" width="100%" horizontalAlign="left">
                    <mx:Label text="{data.resizingCode + ' ' + data.charg_st}"/>
                    <mx:Label text="{data.fingerSize}"/>
                    <mx:Label text="{((new Number(data.carats))/100).toString()}"/>
                    <mx:Label text="{data.color}"/>
                    <mx:Label text="{data.clarity}"/>
                    <mx:Label text="{data.lgort_fp}"/>
                    <mx:Label text="{data.net_price_fp}"/>
                </mx:VBox>
            </mx:HBox>
            <mx:Button label="Order" enabled="{data.product_type == 'C'}" width="50%"/>
        </mx:VBox>
        <mx:Spacer width="15%"/>
    </mx:HBox>

</mx:VBox>
```

Regards,
BS_C3

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<mx:Label text="{data.label1}"/>
```

? (`label1` being a property of your objects)

Comment: Hi!
Yes, that was the first thing I did and it did not work. What I get is something like [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] ... Given that it didn't work, I used a casted "data" as an object of type "custom class". But it did not work either... -_-'

Comment: Interesting, then please make sure your data type is "printable".

Comment: Hi! 
what do you mean by "printable"?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `labelField` field within your list, see [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/using_data_providers/)

```
<mx:List dataProvider="{myDataProvider}" labelField="label1"/>
```

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for your answer but your solution does not fit my problem... 
The item renderer that I've created has a lot of controls and I have the same issue with all the controls... (other labels, images, etc...)

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your custom class as a variable somewhere in your component. Once you declare an instance of the class, Flex might have more success identifying the properties of the class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
  <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
      private var myClass:CustomClass;
    ]]> 
  </mx:Script>
    <mx:Component id="Item">
        <mx:VBox width="180">
         ...
```

[thelost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283647/thelost) had it right with his code too. You should be able to use

```
<mx:Label text="{data.label1}"/>
```

to access your class's properties in your `itemRenderer`.

Edit: I'm sure you've done this, but also double check that you've set the `dataProvider` in your `HorizontalList` to a `[Bindable]` declaration of your `CustomClass`.